# Error in C++ String Program

Tags: c++, string, loops

This program I am making has the user enter a string and a character and then displays the number of times that character appears in the string. For some reason every time I run this program it always says the character appears 0 times in the string. I need some help identifying the problem and fixing it. Thanks!

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string input;
    char character;
    int charCount = 0;

    cout << "Enter a string:" << endl;
    getline(cin, input);
    cout << "Enter a character:" << endl;
    cin  >> character;
    int i = input.find(character);
    while (i < 0)
    {
          charCount++;
          i = input.find(character, (i + 1));  
    }
    cout << character << " appears in the string, " << input << ", " << charCount << " times." << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in the loop condition

```
int i = input.find(character);  // if the character is in the string, it will return a number i > 0
while (i < 0) // will not enter loop
{
      charCount++;
      i = input.find(character, (i + 1));  
}
```

Also, charCount is going to increase with every character you encounter in the string based on this logic.

Comment: Thank you Tah Tatsumoto, I changed the the condition to (i >= 0) and it worked perfectly